# Attempting to use the Laplace transform to solve a second order ordinary differential equation with a piece wise forcing function.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Thanks to everyone who will bare with me and read this attempt and further validate it correct and improve upon it or otherwise correct its wrong.

The question:
$$     
y''(t)+2y'(t)+y(t)=u\left( t-\frac { \pi  }{ 3 }  \right) sin(t)
$$

While y(0)=0 and y'(0)=1

Some notation:

$$
u\left( t-\frac { \pi  }{ 3 }  \right) \left\{  0\quad ,\quad t\quad <\frac {\pi }{3}; 1\quad,\quad t\quad>\frac { \pi  }{ 3 }  \right\} 
$$

Attempt:

Using trigonometry:

sin(t-pi/3)=sin(t)cos(pi/3)-cos(t)sin(pi/3)

therefore:

2sin(t-pi/3)=sqrt(3)sin(t)-cos(t) eqn. 1

also since:

cos(t-pi/3)=cos(t)cos(pi/3)-sin(t)sin(pi/3)

then:

2cos(t-pi/3)=sqrt(3)cos(t)-sin(t) eqn. 2

now we calculate   eqn. 2 +sqrt(3)*eqn. 1

2sqrt(3)sin(t-pi/3)+2cos(t-pi/3)=3sin(t)+sin(t)

Finally we arrive at the conclusion that:

sin(t)=(sqrt(3)/2)sin(t-pi/3)+0.5cos(t-pi/3)..... p=sqrt(3)/2

so

$$
y''(t)+2y'(t)+y(t)=u\left( t-\frac { \pi  }{ 3 }  \right) \left( \frac { \sqrt { 3 }  }{ 2 } \sin { \left( t-\frac { \pi  }{ 3 }  \right)  } +\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \cos { \left( t-\frac { \pi  }{ 3 }  \right)  }  \right) 
$$
$$
 L \left( y''(t)+2y'(t)+y(t)=u\left( t-\frac { \pi  }{ 3 }  \right) \left( \frac { \sqrt { 3 }  }{ 2 } \sin { \left( t-\frac { \pi  }{ 3 }  \right)  } +\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \cos { \left( t-\frac { \pi  }{ 3 }  \right)  }  \right)  \right) 
$$

$$
s^{ 2 }Y-sy(0)-y'(0)+2sY-2y(0)+Y={ e }^{ -\frac { \pi  }{ 3 } s }\left( \frac { \sqrt { 3 }  }{ 2 } \left( \frac { 1 }{ { s }^{ 2 }+1 }  \right) +\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \left( \frac { s }{ { s }^{ 2 }+1 }  \right)  \right) 
$$

We can simplify:
$$
       Y={ e }^{ -\frac { \pi  }{ 3 } s }\left( \frac { \sqrt { 3 }  }{ 2 } \left( \frac { 1 }{ \left( { s }^{ 2 }+1 \right) { \left( s+1 \right)  }^{ 2 } }  \right) +\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \left( \frac { s }{ \left( { s }^{ 2 }+1 \right) { \left( s+1 \right)  }^{ 2 } }  \right)  \right) +\frac { 1 }{ { \left( s+1 \right)  }^{ 2 } } 
$$

Using partial fractions methods we can derive that:
$$
Y={ e }^{ -\frac { \pi  }{ 3 } s }\left( \frac { \sqrt { 3 }  }{ 2 } \left( \frac { 1 }{ 2 } \left( \frac { 1 }{ { \left( s+1 \right)  }^{ 2 } }  \right) +\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \left( \frac { 1 }{ s+1 }  \right) -\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \left( \frac { s }{ { s }^{ 2 }+1 }  \right)  \right) +\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \left( \frac { 1 }{ 2 } \left( \frac { 1 }{ { s }^{ 2 }+1 }  \right) -\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \left( \frac { 1 }{ { \left( s+1 \right)  }^{ 2 } }  \right)  \right)  \right) +\frac { 1 }{ { \left( s+1 \right)  }^{ 2 } } 
$$

Finally (unnnnnnnhhhhh) we can inverse Laplace to get:

$$
y(t)={ e }^{ -t }t+u\left( t-\frac { \pi  }{ 3 }  \right) \left( \frac { \sqrt { 3 }  }{ 4 } \left( { e }^{ -\left( t-\frac { \pi  }{ 3 }  \right)  }+{ e }^{ -\left( t-\frac { \pi  }{ 3 }  \right)  }\left( t-\frac { \pi  }{ 3 }  \right) +\cos { \left( t-\frac { \pi  }{ 3 }  \right)  }  \right) +\frac { 1 }{ 4 } \left( \sin { \left( t-\frac { \pi  }{ 3 }  \right) -{ e }^{ -\left( t-\frac { \pi  }{ 3 }  \right)  }\left( t-\frac { \pi  }{ 3 }  \right)  }  \right)  \right) 
$$

Alright, I couldn't find anything to check my work so could someone help me please? thanks in advance again your help is appreciated.

P.S.:(1)This material is new to me and I am no expert, hence why I am asking. 
(2!)I apologise in advance for my lack of skill in using this site's math-typing function and formats.
(3)I apologise for all the grammer and spelling mistakes above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,
\begin{align}
   \mathscr{L}\{y'\} & = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}y'(t)dt \\
   & = e^{-st}y(t)|_{t=0}^{\infty}+s\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}y(t)dt \\
   & = -y(0)+s\mathscr{L}\{y\}  = s\mathscr{L}\{y\}
\end{align}
Then, using the above, the transform of the second derivative is
\begin{align}
   \mathscr{L}\{y''\} & =\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}y''(t)dt \\
                      & = e^{-st}y'(t)|_{t=0}^{\infty}+s\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}y'(t)dt \\
     & = -y'(0)+s\mathscr{L}\{y'\} \\
     & = -1 + s^{2}\mathscr{L}\{y\}
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
   \mathscr{L}\{y''+2y'+y\} & =s^{2}\mathscr{L}\{y\}+2s\mathscr{L}\{y\})+\mathscr{L}\{y\}-1 \\
    & = (s+1)^{2}\mathscr{L}\{y\}-1.
\end{align}
And this must equal
\begin{align}
   \mathscr{L}\left\{u(t-\frac{\pi}{3})\sin(t)\right\}
   & = \int_{\pi/3}^{\infty}e^{-st}\sin(t)dt \\
   & = \int_{\pi/3}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-st+it}-e^{-st-it}}{2i}dt \\
   & = \frac{1}{2i}\left[\frac{1}{i-s}e^{-st+it}-\frac{1}{i+s}e^{-st-it}\right]_{t=\pi/3}^{\infty} \\
   & = \frac{e^{-s\pi/3}}{2i}\left[\frac{e^{i\pi/3}}{s-i}+\frac{e^{-i\pi/3}}{s+i}\right] \\
   & = \frac{e^{-s\pi/3}}{2i}\left[\frac{\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}{s-i}+\frac{\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}{s+i}\right] \\
   & = \frac{e^{-s\pi/3}}{2i}\left[\frac{s-\sqrt{3}}{(s-i)(s+i)}\right]
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$
   \mathscr{L}\{y\}=\frac{1}{(s+1)^{2}}+\frac{e^{-s\pi/3}}{2i(s+1)^{2}}\left[\frac{s-\sqrt{3}}{(s-i)(s+i)}\right].
$$
We have slightly different Laplace transforms.

Comment: Interesting you used the exponential form of the sine and cosine functions, that is much easier than what I did (mainly because I am not yet comfortable with i) are our answers both equal or is there a difference (would be great if you inverse the laplace on that) Thanks!